# Question on arithmetic. Time and Work.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> Three diggers dug a ditch 324 m deep in six days working
>   simultaneously. During one shift, the third digger digs as many metres
>   more than the second as the second digs more than the first. The third
>   digger's work in 10 days is equal to the first digger's work in 14
>   days. How many metres does the first digger dig per shift?

I don't understand what is the duration of each shift.

Is my approach correct?  (I haven't arrived at the answer.)

My approach:

Let the 3 diggers be A,B,C.

Let they dig a m/day, b m/day, c m/day respectively.

ATQ:

10c=14a

or, 5c=7a.------(1)

also,

(a+b+c)*6=324----(2)

and

Let duration of each shift be t

(c-b)*t =(b-a)*t

c-b =b-a-----(3)

Solving 3 equations we get b=18 m/day.

They have asked to find how many metres does the first digger dig per shift. I can't understand what they have meant, hence not able to find that.

Comment: Everything you have done thus far is correct.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sir, they have asked to find how many metres does the first digger dig per shift. I can't understand what they have meant, hence not able to find that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are told that the third digger digs as many metres more than the second digs than the second digs more than the first.  Let $d$ be that difference.  Then $d = c - b = b - a$.  The amount the first digger digs is $a = b - d = 18~\text{m} - d$ and the amount the third digger digs is $c = b + d = 18~\text{m} + d$.  Since we know that $7a = 5c$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
5c &  = 7a\\
5(18~\text{m} + d) & = 7(18~\text{m} - d)\\
90~\text{m} + 5d & = 126~\text{m} - 7d\\
12d & = 36~\text{m}\\
d & = 3~\text{m}
\end{align*}
from which we conclude that $a = 18~\text{m} - 3~\text{m} = 15~\text{m}$.

Comment: So, per shift means per day?

Comment: Indeed, it does.

Comment: @Soumee I was thinking that that might be your problem. Typically, workers work one shift per day (but they might not). You need to assume that they do to get an answer.

Comment: @Lucas Right Sir....